# Does Hazelcast supports SQL queries like Apache Ignite?

Tags: sql, hazelcast, ignite

Looking for comparison with Apache Ignite - does Hazelcast have SQL support?

Answer (score 8):

No Hazelcast does not have full SQL support. Hazelcast offers a Predicate API which can also be written in the form of the Where-Clause in a SQL-alike style, however it does not provide the full SQL standard.

Comment: For more info see here: http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.8.6/manual/html-single/index.html#querying-with-sql